# Excel Chart Object without source data in Word going back to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel object chart in word. The chart is a line graph. The data is there because when I mouse over the line, I see each individual x and y value. However, the word file chart was sent to me. So, when I left click and "edit data" I get an error message that says

"The linked file is nto available. To edit the link, click the File tab. Click the Info tab, and then under related Documents, click Edit Links to Files"

Clearly, since this was not created on my machine, I can't edit the links and find the data.

I found a macro that will take a chart and recreate the data when the source data is lost or corrupted but that was written for or only works in Excel (or at least I don't know how to manipulate it to work with Word). The issue is when I copy and paste the chart into an Excel workbook, the chart copies but my data disappears. I guess that it tries to find the source data and then can't find it and makes it blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple Copy and Paste may not work as you expected and will end up with an error. Use Paste Special option with "Keep Source Formatting and Link Data". It will ensure the source format is applied to the another worksheet.

Right click > Paste Special > "Keep Source Formatting and Link Data"

Hope this helps.